# solving ode with time-array input - PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, input, ode, odeint

I am trying to solve this problem, searched stack overflow and couldn't find an answer.

I want to integrate a set of state equations, where my inputs that I want to pass as arguments, are arrays as the same length of t.

Example of time-invariant arguments:

```
# state function
def state(x, t, u_in):
    u     = x[0]
    v     = x[1]
    w     = x[2]
    phi   = x[3]
    theta = x[4]
    psi   = x[5]
    h     = x[6]

    ax   = u_in[0]
    ay   = u_in[1]
    az   = u_in[2]
    p    = u_in[3]
    q    = u_in[4]
    r    = u_in[5]
    pdot = u_in[6]
    qdot = u_in[7]
    rdot = u_in[8]

    xdot = np.zeros(len(x))
    xdot[0] = ax - g * np.sin(theta) + r * v - q * w
    xdot[1] = ay + g * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta) + p * w - r * u
    xdot[2] = az + g * np.cos(phi) * np.cos(theta) + q * u - p * v
    xdot[3] = p + (q * np.sin(phi) + r * np.cos(phi)) * np.tan(theta)
    xdot[4] = q * np.cos(phi) - r * np.sin(phi)
    xdot[5] = (q * np.sin(phi) + r * np.cos(phi)) / np.cos(theta)
    xdot[6] = u * np.sin(theta) - v * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta) - w * np.cos(phi) * np.cos(theta)
    return xdot


# initial condition
x0 = np.zeros(7)

# set problem
n = 101
t = np.linspace(0, 10, num=n)
uinp = np.zeros(9)
uinp[0] = 0
uinp[1] = 0
uinp[2] = -g
uinp[3] = 0
uinp[4] = 0
uinp[5] = 0
uinp[6] = 0
uinp[7] = 0
uinp[8] = 0


# solve ODE
x = odeint(state, x0, t, args=(uinp,))
```

This works fine because my inputs are time invariant.

What I want to do and it doesn't work is to set my uinp as np.zeros_like(t) and solve the same ODE.

i.e.

```
uinp = np.zeros((n, 9))
uinp[:, 0] = 0
uinp[:, 1] = 0
uinp[:, 2] = -g
uinp[:, 3] = 0
uinp[:, 4] = 0
uinp[:, 5] = 0
uinp[:, 6] = 0
uinp[:, 7] = 0
uinp[:, 8] = 0
```

and I get this error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
enter code here
```

Using a loop for each timepiece input is not an option, as it creates too much overhead and it takes forever to run this simulation.

Thanks for the help and insights

Comment: Where does the time variance come from? If it is a continuous process, use interpolation to resolve the time dependence. This kind of question appears here about once a month, perhaps too many of them get deleted after getting a solution. See the search results in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bode%5D+setting+an+array+element+with+a+sequence

Comment: It comes from real world data. I already have a 'working' solution: I simply created my own RK45 algorithm that reads for each timestep the corresponding input value. It's done in C and compiled as a DLL. My issue with this is that every time that I have to change my state equations (and I have to change it a lot), I have to create a new dll, in C. It's simply not practical.

Comment: Using a for-loop, as everyone answers once a month, doesn't work for me. A simple case with python loop takes more than an hour to solve this simple case of state equations, while with my DLL approach it takes a less than 3 min.

I will try to explain what I want:
I have created a parameter estimation problem that solves a simulation. My state and observation equations are dependent upon the parameters, so a simple scipy.curve_fit won't do it. I had to basically rewrite what probably scipy is doing to account for this

Comment: So my problem consists of a well defined time array (t), a well defined input array that is the same length of t. Python's ode simple can't handle this simple situation and I can't understand why.

Comment: Is the time array equidistant? Then you could implement the idea of the answer, compute the index from the time, return the function value at the index. If not, then scipy.interpolate.interp1d can be used with the option `kind="previous" to get a zero-hold extension of the data to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you make your state function time dependent? If I understood correctly, then this part:

```
ax   = u_in[0]
ay   = u_in[1]
az   = u_in[2]
p    = u_in[3]
q    = u_in[4]
r    = u_in[5]
pdot = u_in[6]
qdot = u_in[7]
rdot = u_in[8]
```

should depend on time `t`:

```
ax   = u_in[t, 0]
ay   = u_in[t, 1]
az   = u_in[t, 2]
p    = u_in[t, 3]
q    = u_in[t, 4]
r    = u_in[t, 5]
pdot = u_in[t, 6]
qdot = u_in[t, 7]
rdot = u_in[t, 8]
```

You might need to find a way of mapping the input `t`, which may be a `float` to the corresponding column in u_in

Comment: What fields would that select when `t=1.234`? (none, the interpreter would exit with an error, only integers allowed as indices.)

Comment: That's why I mentioned at the end, that he needs to find a way of mapping the columns of u_in to the timesteps. ```t```, as of now, can not be used for that

Comment: Yes, if piecewise constant or zero-order hold is a sufficient approximation of the data. The error of the resulting solution can of course only be as good as the error in the input approximation allows.